# Reference for extreme value theorem.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, semicontinuous-functions, extreme-value-theorem

I look for a reference of the Extreme Value Theorem for semicontinuous functions defined on a topological space.
I know the proof, but I want to cite this result in my work.

Comment: How about [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtremeValueTheorem.html)?

Comment: This is an interesting predicament. Would you feel the need to cite the Pythagorean Theorem? At what point do theorems enter "folklore"?

Comment: This one depends on who you write for. However no one has yet answered me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer to [Extreme Value Theorem and Semicontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291484). This contains an explicit reference:

Aliprantis, Charalambos D., and C. Kim. "Border (1999). Infinite dimensional analysis: a hitchhiker’s guide." (1986)

Answer (score 0):

The theorem for semi-continuous functions is stated in Nicolas Bourbaki, "General Topology", Ch. IV, § 6, no. 2, theorem 3.

In the 1966 edition *Elements of Mathematics. General Topology. Part 1 (Ch. 1-IV)*, by Hermann / Addison-Wesley that's p. 361.